# Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'runtimeManifests' during up-to-date check

Tags: android, gradle

org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'runtimeManifests' during up-to-date check.

I face issue multiple time and i can't resolve it , i got some reference for Disable Instant Run but it's not working.

i have use 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPicker:v1.0.10'

Comment: Upgrading ClassPaths and Dependencies worked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this solution that worked for me : I did a gradle clean.

Find the file gradlew (linux) or gradlew.bat (windows). In my case it was in the project folder (it might be in your sdk folder).

Open a prompt and type :

```
gradlew clean
```

Maybe a simple Project > Clean may have also worked, but I didn't try it before.

Hope it helps.